# How to use SetPlaceholderText which has broken IDL definition with late binding

Tags: c#, .net, com, ms-office, netoffice

I want to make office add-in which will be supported by any 2007+ offices. Setting different add-in version for different offices seems impossible, all offices are loading add-in info from same registry key. So I decided to use netoffice. 

 
Now when I use `ContentControl.SetPlaceholderText(null, null, "some text")` I get `DISP_E_TYPEMISMATCH` exception. According to [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/0c03837b-aca1-4cb6-81b7-f4fac8f36a04/possible-bug-in-wordcontentcontrol?forum=worddev) reason is poorly writen IDL definition: integer default value for pointer. Funny thing is [if first parameter is not null 
then third is ignored](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb256831(v=office.12).aspx). 

I've tried to pass `Missing.Value`. 

When I've tried to use my custom binder

```
contentControl.InstanceType.InvokeMember("SetPlaceholderText",
            BindingFlags.InvokeMethod,
            new MyBinder(), 
            contentControl.UnderlyingObject,
            new object[] { null, null, placeholder });
```

`MyBinder` methods was never called. 

`ContentControl` has `PlaceholderText` property, which has `Value`. `Value` is read/write property according to documentation, but says it's readonly when I write my value into it.

So how to set placeholder?

Comment: Hmm, no, that can't be it, you are not relying on the [defaultvalue] since you specify null explicitly.  Random guess: review [quirk #4](http://shaunakelly.com/word/word-development/placeholders-in-word-content-controls-for-developers.html).

Comment: @HansPassant, I am able to reproduce this issue and as I can see, quirk #4 is not applicable here. The point is that the placeholder still *can* be set through VBA: `control.SetPlaceHolderText , , "My Placeholder"`, but the same seems to be impossible from C#.